# Breadcrumbs Not Displaying Properly

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I am experiencing problems with breadcrumb trails inconsistently not displaying correctly. I am using the core breadcrumb module, without any others installed. (I did have Custom Breadcrumbs installed but have since uninstalled and removed it.)

I have links to nodes nested in parent items in the main menu like this:
Home > Chapter > Topic > Subtopic.
Most nodes are displaying the breadcrumbs like that, which is what I want. However, a few are displaying like this:
Home > Subtopic (not showing the chapter and topic under which they are listed)

I believe I started getting this error when I changed the numerical weight of the menu items in structure > menu. I have since changed their depth, changed their parent menu item, flushed caches, nothing has worked. It is only a few nodes with the problem and they were originally working as expected. I cannot recreate this problem either. If I create new nodes they show the proper breadcrumb trail. The items in question are all as they should be in weight and parent menu item position they should be. If I install Custom Breadcrumbs I can force the breadcrumb trail to the desired state. Is there a table that I can flush in the database that will fix this problem? Is there a way to fix this without deleting the node and recreating it?

**Edit:** I found the problem. I have links to these nodes in two different menus on the same page. Drupal is using the other menu I created instead of the Main-Menu to make the breadcrumb trail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is having multiple menus with the node's links on the node's page at the same time. Instead of using the main-menu, Drupal is using the other menu you have created, which has no parent-items. You need to override it's default function.

1. Install [Menu Breadcrumb](https://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb)
2. Go to admin/config/user-interface/menu-breadcrumb
3. Re-order the list to reflect the priority in which you want to be used for the breadcrumb trail
   AND/OR
   Deselect the menus you do not want to use for the Breadcrumb trail

Answer (score 1):

It looks you need to fix the breadcrumbs for a particular contentHere is my idea.

> - In your theme, in template.php implement theme_breadcrumns(), as below
> - Inside the theme_breadcrumbs() implementation check type of node using

[menu_get_object()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

// Lets assume your content type name is chapter
  $node = menu_get_object();
  $node_type = $node->type; 
  if($store == "chapter") {
     $links[0] =  l(t('Home'), '<front>');
     $links[1] =  t('Chapter');
     $links[2] =  t('Topic');
     $links[3] =  t($node->title); // Considering Sub topic as node title
     drupal_set_breadcrumb($links); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found a solution with just a module. The problem was that I had two links to these nodes in two different menus on the same page. Drupal was using the other menu I created instead of the Main-Menu to make the breadcrumb trail.